# Built in function to combine affine transforms in OpenCV?

Tags: c++, opencv

Is there any built-in function in Opencv which combines affine transforms?
I can write it by myself too, but I'd stick to using library functions when possible.

Cheers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right now I do this:

- I allocate a1, a2, r matrices, all 3x3 eyes,
- I replace the top part of the first two with the transformation matrices a1aff, a2aff.
- r = a2*a1
- return the first two rows of r.

This solution will do for now.

Comment: still no openCV library function for this?