# Combine two affine Transformations Matrices in OpenCV

Tags: c++, opencv, matrix, affinetransform

I have two 2x3 Matrices A and B - each one is for affine Transformation. 
I need to combine A and B into a thrid Matrix C which will combine the affine transformation from A and B into one Matrix.

How do I need to multiply them?

A*B or B*A ?

The difference is that either A or B gets transposed or does it make any difference at all?

I read a further solution is to use 3x3 matrices and copy into the first two rows and only use the first two rows in the result. But it comes down to the same question if it is A*B or B*A.

Furthermore, is there an easy way to implement this in OpenCV or do I need to implement every step as described above?

Comment: Neither one should be transposed. Add a third row. The multiplication order depends on your scenario.

Comment: it makes a difference and depends on the sequence, which transformation should be performed first. But beware that 2x3 affine transformations cant be multiplied this way, you'll first have to extend them to 3x3 matrices by adding a 0 0 1 row at bottom. After that you compute C = BA if you want to perform A before B or C = AB if you want to perform B first.

Comment: Thank you, that worked. 
But OpenCV does not provide any function fort that?

Comment: you could easily write a small function that implicitly multiplies two affine 2x3 matrices without adding an additional row. Maybe there is hidden such a function somewhere within openCV, but if, I don't know it...

Comment: in 2012 it looks like there wasn't ... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13557066/built-in-function-to-combine-affine-transforms-in-opencv

Comment: @Micka do you want to make your comment as an answer so I can accept it ?

Comment: Sure I'll do - i just wanted to make sure to give you credit

Comment: @Micka I did so, thank you for your insights

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following function combines this two matrices:

```
  Mat AffineTransform::concatenateMatrix(Mat first, Mat second){

        Mat mul1 = Mat::eye(3, 3, CV_64F);
        Mat mul2 = Mat::eye(3, 3, CV_64F);
        Mat x_;
        Mat temp_inv_;
        Mat mul_r;
        first.convertTo(temp_inv_, CV_64F);
        second.convertTo(x_, CV_64F);

        temp_inv_.row(0).copyTo(mul1.row(0));
        temp_inv_.row(1).copyTo(mul1.row(1));

        x_.row(1).copyTo(mul2.row(1));
        x_.row(0).copyTo(mul2.row(0));

        try{
            mul_r = mul1*mul2;
        }
        catch (Exception& e){
            const char* err_msg = e.what();
            cout << err_msg;
        }

        mul1.release();
        mul2.release();
        temp_inv_.release();

        return mul_r;
}
```

Comment: change `mul_r = mul1*mul2;` to `mul_r = mul2*mul1;`, which is the correct operation to *1. warpaffine(Mat firirst) 2. warpaffine(Mat second)*